# Cant get hold of service instance from activity

Tags: android, service

I have written a service which is started from onCreate of a class that extends Application as below.

```
class Example extends Application {
   private BleService bleService;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    startBleService(this);
   }

   private final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        bleService = ((BleService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        bleService = null;
    }
   };

   public BleService getBleService(){
     return bleService;
   }

   public void startBleService(Context context) {
    context.bindService(new Intent(context, BleService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   }
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BleService getService() {
        return BleService.this;
    }
}
```

When I debug this code, the service connection gets called and I can see that bleService is started and is not null. Yet when I try to call getBleService from an activity it is null. I have tested that bleService gets assigned far before the actual call to getBleService so that cant be the reason it is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you add `Example` class in manifest file

Comment: Yes. It otherwise wouldn't have started the service right?

Comment: Double check your BLEService's LocalBinder's getService call. Is it actually returning the started instance of the service?

Comment: @Puneet I have added the LocalBinder code. I am not keeping an instance of service so that is what I return. Am I supposed to keep a reference to the service inside the service?

Comment: You can always return BLESerice.this. That should suffice if you created LocalBinder implementation within BLEService.  Consider posting BLEService code as well.

Comment: Add Logs to your service in Ondestroy and onstartcommand.
Verify if your service is started and also this might give you insight if the service dies out before you call

Comment: Thanks guys. I got the answer. It was my stupidity actually. To get an instance of the Example for calling I was using singleton pattern which was actually called after the onCreate and hence the instance was null and new Example instance was created. I just set instance = this in onCreate and its working fine.